# Radio Button Checked doesn't Trigger right

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="AMRadioButton" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="TypeGroup"
                                OnCheckedChanged="AMRadioButton_CheckedChanged" Text="Accounting Date" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="LMRadioButton" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="TypeGroup"
                                OnCheckedChanged="LMRadioButton_CheckedChanged" Text="Loan Date" />
```

and i have a code behind

```
 protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AMRadioButton.Checked = true)
        {
            prenda.Bcode = BranchCodetxtbox.Text;
            prenda.AccountingMonth = YearDropDownList.SelectedValue + "/" + MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue;
            prenda.Jprincipal = Convert.ToDecimal(JewelryTextBox.Text);
            prenda.Aprincipal =  Convert.ToDecimal(ApplianceTextBox.Text);
            prenda.Cprincipal =  Convert.ToDecimal(CellphoneTextBox.Text);
            user.UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            servs.UploadPrendaAM(prenda, user);
            Session["Count"] = "1";
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Success!');window.location='DataEntryPage.aspx';</script>");

        }
        else if (LMRadioButton.Checked = true)
        {
            prenda.Bcode = BranchCodetxtbox.Text;
            prenda.LoanMonth = YearDropDownList.SelectedValue + "/" + MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue;
            prenda.Jprincipal =  Convert.ToDecimal(JewelryTextBox.Text);
            prenda.Aprincipal =  Convert.ToDecimal(ApplianceTextBox.Text);
            prenda.Cprincipal =  Convert.ToDecimal(CellphoneTextBox.Text);
            user.UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            servs.UploadPrendaLM(prenda, user);
            Session["Count"] = "1";
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Success!');window.location='DataEntryPage.aspx';</script>");

        }
    }
```

the problem is even though i have checked/selected the the LMradiobutton the code still goes inside the `if(AMRadioButton.Checked = true)` which is not what i want, ofcourse when i ticked the LMradiobutton the code supposed to be `else if (LMRadioButton.Checked = true)` in here no in the amradiobutton.Checked.

do i miss something? please help

Comment: it seems the two radio buttons trigger different events (AMRadioButton_CheckedChanged and LMRadioButton_CheckedChanged). have you checked those events? the code posted here comes from a different event handler (addbutton_click).

Comment: im just testing if they are checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if(AMRadioButton.Checked == true)
```

or

```
else if (LMRadioButton.Checked == true)
```

Use == for checking conditions or as compare operator

Use = when assigning values.

You are assigning value to checked property which will always return true.

Comment: Great! it worked. it seems that the fundamentals are not sinking into me hehe thanks! ill accept and upvote you as soon as i can :)